# Cannot export functions in a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2005

I have a .lib which has a function that I want to make into a DLL.

In the project properties, I have done 2 things, 
1. In the C/C++ -> General -> Additional Directories: added the path for the .h file.
2. In the Linker-> General -> Additional Dependies: added the path for the .lib file

Then I made an .h file

```
#ifndef _DFUWRAPPER_H_
#define _DFUWRAPPER_H_

#include <windows.h>
#include "DFUEngine.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

__declspec(dllexport) void helloworld(void);
__declspec(dllexport) void  InitDLL();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif 

#endif
```

and made the .cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "DFUWrapper.h"

#ifdef _MANAGED
#pragma managed(push, off)
#endif

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    return TRUE;
}

#ifdef _MANAGED
#pragma managed(pop)
#endif

void helloworld(void)
{
    printf("hello world DFU");
}

DFUEngine* PyDFUEngine()
{
    return new DFUEngine();
}

void delDFUEngine(DFUEngine *DFUe)
{
    DFUe->~DFUEngine();
}

void  PyInitDLL(DFUEngine *DFUe)
{
    return DFUe->InitDLL();
}
```

I made a test with the function helloword. I can see this function in the DLL but not the InitDLL function.
How can I come around this? Please help

Comment: Visual Studio, presumably. What version? What do you mean by you can't "see" the function? Show some data/errors/output.

Comment: Am using VS2005. I am checking in dependence walker. I can see the halloworld() function but not InitDLL()

Comment: In your .c file it's `PyInitDll`. In your .h it's `InitDll`

Answer (score 0):

Define the following in your DLL header file

```
#if defined (_MSC_VER)
#if defined (MY_DLL_EXPORTS)
#define MY_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MY_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#else
#define MY_EXPORT
#endif
```

Declare your function using that macro

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

MY_EXPORT void helloworld(void);
MY_EXPORT void InitDLL();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And in your .cpp

```
MY_EXPORT void helloworld(void)
{
    printf("hello world DFU");
}

MY_EXPORT void InitDLL()
{
    /// blahblah 
}
```

Compile your DLL with MY_DLL_EXPORT defintion.... 
But be sure that it's not define when you want IMPORT ....

Answer (score 0):

I like exporting functions from DLLs [using **.DEF files**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx).

This has the added benefit of avoiding name mangling: not only the C++ complex mangling, but also the one happening with `__stdcall` and `extern "C"` functions (e.g. `_myfunc@12`).

You may want to simply add a DEF file for your DLL, e.g.:

```
LIBRARY   MYDLL
EXPORTS
   InitDLL     @1
   helloworld  @2
   ... other functions ...
```